# SqlAlchemy association_proxy filter returned array (_AssociationList)

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

im using an `association_proxy` like this:

```py
study_participantions = association_proxy("quests", "study_participant",creator=lambda sp: sp.questionnaire)
```

I my Db there is:

- **A Patient table**
- **A StudyParticipant table**
- **A Questionnaire table**

**Patient** and **Questionnaire** are a **Many-To-One relationship**

A **Questionnaire** can be Part of a **StudyParticiapnt** via a **One-To-One** relationship

**StudyParticipant** and **Patient** are **not directly linked** since StudyParticipant can be annonymous.

So via getter and setter i can query the Patient trough the questionnaire.

Since im working with an existing codebase I have to keep the patient inside the questionnaire

The StudyParticipant can be find via the proxy from the Patient. getting and setting works but if the Questionnaire is not part of a StudyParticiapnt the returned array contains `None` values is it possible to filter them out so i would get a clean array? For sure it should still be an
`sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy._AssociationList` so appending and removing to it would still work.

Simplified Classes:

```py
class Patient(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'patient'

    id           = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    study_participantions = association_proxy("quests", "study_participant",creator=lambda sp: sp.questionnaire)

class StudyParticipant(Model): #better name would be participation
    __tablename__ = "study_participant"

    id                 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    pseudonym           = Column(String(40), nullable = True)

    questionnaire      = relationship("Questionnaire", backref="study_participant",uselist=False) # why go via the StudyQuestionnaire 
  
    
class Questionnaire(Model, metaclass=QuestionnaireMeta):
    __tablename__ = 'questionnaire'

    id                 = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    patient_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('patient.id'), nullable=True)
    patient    = relationship('Patient', backref='quests',
                              primaryjoin=questionnaire_patient_join)
```